# Why does vs code prefix my file search with a hash? i.e. '#'

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I search for files in vs code I press CMD+T and a popup appears so I can search my projects files.

For some reason the search input box defaults with a hash '#' which I always have to first delete before typing in the filename I want to search for.

Is there a way to remove this and why does it do this in the first place?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

CMD+T is the keyboard shortcut for 'Go to symbol' not file search.
If you are looking for files, CMD+P is the keyboard shortcut on macOS.
[image: screenprint]

Comment: I'm coming to VS Code from Sublime Text and had installed a plugin or setting (cant remember now) that was supposed to emulate keyboard shortcuts for ST3.  CMD+T was search for files (i guess because symbol search didn't exist in ST3).   I've been bugged by this for a month and finally searched and found this.  Thank you!

Comment: Super strange it's diff from windows, as someone developing mostly on windows but on a mac for an IOS app